# PostgreSQL database delete automatically after server restart

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

In my windows server i install postgreSQL15. 3 but when the server is restarting after that my all postgreSQL database tabels are deleted. Thanks for help.

Need to solve this issue because it's deleted after 2-3 days and not possible to restore again and again

[Logs of postgreSQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymspu.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [ask] and update your post accordingly. It is not clear what happened? Could you be more specific on the context? Did you upgraded your database from 9 to 15? Also picture are very poor medium to exchange textual data, copy paste and format instead of screenschot.

Comment: Someone is logging in and mucking about.  Review your security practices.